Windows Terminal automatic switch dark/light theme based on Windows settings
I want Windows Terminal to switch theme automatically depending on Windows 10 settings.
This guide says that: "...configure the Terminal to use separate themes for light and dark mode in the OS and change automatically between those themes when the OS theme changes. To do this, specify the theme property as an object containing the keys light and dark:"
"theme": { "dark": "<Dark Theme Name>", "light": "<Light Theme Name>" },

So I did in my settings.json I added the following line:
"theme": { "dark": "One Half Dark", "light": "Solarized Light" },
"themes": []

But I get the error:
• The specified "theme" was not found in the list of themes. Temporarily falling back to the default value.
• The specified "theme" was not found in the list of themes. Temporarily falling back to the default value.

Then, I tried the following:
"theme": { "dark": "One Half Dark", "light": "Solarized Light" },
"themes": ["One Half Dark", "Solarized Light"]

resulting in the following error:
Failed to load settings
Settings could not be loaded from file. Check for syntax errors, including trailing commas.
{Application Error}
The exception %s (0x

Temporarily using the Windows Terminal default settings.

How to solve that?

Windows Terminal Theme based on System Theme
There is already this feature in the settings, without change json file.
Open WT > Appearance > Application Theme > Use Windows Theme


Great thanks! Will it cascade on all the profile? I was searching for the same option in different profiles but I cannot find it... perhaps this is worth another question?

Yes. for all profiles. I don't know yet for one profile.  Perhaps u can make new question for that.

I just tried. The setting you mentioned changes only the Windows Terminal app light/dark theme, but it seems but that won't affect the scheme used in the different profiles that seems to be fixed. I'll open a new question or I could directly post in windows terminal discussion board on GH.

Yes. This is only for light dark mode following the system.
That's up to you. thanks.

Note that color scheme != application theme. The question is about the former whereas this answer is about the latter.

If you really want the auto color scheme, I suggest to give up windows terminal, just use Visutal Studio Code, it support the auto color switching, just open vscode and run a terminal

This doesn't appear to be documented on the Windows Terminal site, but the color_scheme JSON config property also accepts the same {"dark": <dark scheme>, "light": <light scheme>} syntax as the application theme. Here's the bare minimum config to make that work:
{
    "$help": "https://aka.ms/terminal-documentation",
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
    "profiles": 
    {
        "defaults": 
        {
            "colorScheme": {"dark": "One Half Dark", "light": "One Half Light"},
        }
    }
}


Therefore, to match both application theme and terminal color scheme to your system theme, you'd want to set application theme in the app's settings (or by using the "theme": "system" config key), then spelunk into the JSON config to change the default color scheme like I did above.
